# How to resolve issues for ZAP code scanner result

Tags: security

I have cleared the salesforce source code scanner result.

Now in my organization I have done some integration with third part application so I need to clear Zap code scanner result so I have scanned my application in zap code scanner and I got some issue so I want to know that **"How we can resolve these issue"**?

**Issue :1**

X-Frame-Options Header Not Set

**Issue :2**

Application Error Disclosure

**Issue :3**

Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set

**Issue :4**

Cookie No HttpOnly Flag

**Issue 5:**

Cookie Without Secure Flag

**Issue :6**

Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled

**Issue :7**

Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set

**Issue :8**

Cookie set without HttpOnly flag

**Issue :9**

Password Field with Autocomplete enabled

**Issue 10:**

Block cipher algorithms with block size of 64 bits (like DES and 3DES) birthday attack known as Sweet32, CVE-2016-2183

I got similar types of issue

.[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for Issue - 1,4,5,7